# How to store previous value and current value in for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a cursor C1 which selects column status from table test.

Using `for` loop, I have to check the previous value for status is `ERROR` and current value for status is `VALID`.If so then I have to update table `test1`.

E.G.

```
for 1 in 1..c1 loop

 if previous.status = ERROR and current.status then

  update test1.

  end if;

end loop;
```

Please help me how can I store previous and current value from for loop for comparison.

Comment: How it became previous before you update it ? Show your table structure and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: cursor c1 is select status from test; open c1;fetch c1 bulk collect into l_status; for i in 1..l_status.count loop. now inside this loop i would like to store l_previous = i-1 and l_current=i values.then if l_previous ='ERROR and l_current='VALID' then update table oracle;end if;end loop. the status will hold values ERROR,VALID,UPLOADED in tabl etest.

Comment: Doing updates in a loop is very often a bad choice. It's usually a **lot** more efficient doing things with a single update statement. If you post the table structure, some sample data and the expected result of the `update` we can probably find a better approach for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, this should do the work for your with minor changes:

```
declare    
v_previous_status test.status%type;   
cursor c1 
is 
select status 
from test; 

begin   
open c1;   
fetch c1 bulk collect into l_status;    
for i in 1..l_status.count   

if (v_previous = 'ERROR' and l_status(i) = 'VALID' ) then  
update ....  
end if;  
v_previous := l_status(i); 
end loop;  
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would DECLARE your cursor.  DECLARE a variable to hold the previous value.(Set a default because there is no previous at this point)  OPEN your cursor.  FETCH your first record.  Then you would WHILE loop over the rest of the records.  At the end of each WHILE loop you'll do another FETCH.  So you want to set the variable that holds your previous value BEFORE you fetch the next record.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only provided the pseudo-code, I'll give you my pseudo-code to that problem of yours. Consider the following:

```
Initialize previous.status;
Initialize current.status;

SET previous.status;

BEGIN loop

SET current.status;

IF previous.status = ERROR and current.status then
   UPDATE test1
END IF

previous.status = current.status;

END loop
```

'previous.status' is set to 'current.status' before 'END loop' to prepare it to be used in comparison on the next loop which will have its new current.status. It's necessary that the variables that will store the previous and current status must be declared outside the loop.